# str_getcsv to separate lines removes enclosing characters in lines

Tags: php, csv, parsing

`str_getcsv ()` has some odd behaviour. It removes **all** characters that match the enclosing character, instead of **just the enclosing ones**. I'm trying to parse a CSV string (contents of an uploaded file) in two steps:

1. split the CSV string into an array of lines
2. split each line into an array of fields

with this code:

```
$whole_file_string = file_get_contents($file);
$array_of_lines = str_getcsv ($whole_file_string, "\n", "\""); // step 1. split csv into lines
foreach ($array_of_lines as $one_line_string) {
    $splitted_line = str_getcsv ($one_line_string, ",", "\""); // step 2. split line into fields
};
```

In the code example nothing is done with `$splitted_line` for clarity of example

Then I feed this script a file with the following contents: `"text,with,delimiter",secondfield`.
When step 1 is performed the first (and only) element of `$array_of_lines` is `text,with,delimiter,secondfield`. So when step 2 is performed, it splits the line into 4 fields, but that needs to be 2.

I can't use `fgetcsv()` because some string conversion is done (checking BOM, converting encoding accordingly and stuff like that) after reading the file and before splitting it into lines in step 1.

I'm at the point of writing my own string parser (which isn't that complicated for CSV format), but before I do so I want to make sure that that's the best approach. I'm a bit disappointed that the PHP functions are letting me down on this simple (and I guess quite common) use case: processing an uploaded csv file with varying encoding.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm. Strange. I'm fiddling around a bit and I discovered something interesting:

```
$a = str_getcsv("\"@ne piece, @f text\"", "\n");
$b = str_getcsv("\"@ne piece, @f text\"", "\n","\"");
$c = str_getcsv("\"@ne piece, @f text\"", "\n","@");
echo $a; // @ne piece, @f text
echo $b; // @ne piece, @f text
echo $c; // "@ne piece, @f text"
```

So Passing an `@` as enclosing character instead of `"` (or leaving it out and using the default, which is `"` as well) is semantically bullocks, but it does the job. It leaves the enclosing `"` around the field, so if you then `str_getcsv($c, ",")` it results in one value as it should. And if you have a field enclosed in @ it leaves it untouched. I tested that.

It is clear that str_getcsv has its flaws. On splitting to lines it shouldn't strip quotes, just like it doesn't strip `@` when that's the enclosing parameter. But sadly it does and therefore isn't CSV compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be calling `str_getcsv()` on one line at a time, not the whole file.

```
$array_of_lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // split CSV into lines
foreach($array_of_lines as $one_line_string) {
    $splitted_line = str_getcsv($one_line_string, ",", "\""); // split line into fields
}
```

Comment: The `file()` approach isn't working either. It mechanically breaks at line break characters, so when $file has this contents:
`"Enclosed text\r\n
with a line break","foo"\r\n
foo,bar`

it splits into 3 lines instead of 2, because it doesn't get that the first line break is part of an enclosed string. That is not what I want and of course not compliant with the CSV standard (which file() never intended to be).

Comment: Could you use `fgetcsv()` with a `php://memory` stream? First read the file, do the conversions, then write it to `php://memory`.

Comment: No. Both fgetcsv and str_getcsv are interpreting the csv format wrong!
Doesn't matter which one you use. They mess up enclosed data when cutting on newlines, and then it cuts fields on delimiters that were in enclosed field data. 
Check for yourself: `$a = str_getcsv("\"one piece, of text\"", "\n"); $b = str_getcsv($a[0], ","); echo $b[0];  // "one piece"` but it should be `echo $b[0];  // "one piece, of text"`

Comment: Hm. Strange. I'm fiddling around and this seems to work: `$a = str_getcsv("\"@ne piece, @f text\"", "\n","@");`.  Passing an @ as enclosing character instead of " (or leaving it out and using the default, which is " as well) is processed differently, and it doesn't get stripped. Not even when you use it as first and last character of a field. Bizar...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own CSV parser, fully compliant with IETF rfc 4180. 
I'm curious to know if this can be done in regular expressions, those are not my forte.

```
/**
 * Parse a string according to CSV format (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180), with variabele delimiter (default ,).
 * @param string $string    String to be parsed as csv
 * @param string $delimiter character to be used as field delimiter  
 * @return array            Array with for each line an array with csv field values
 */
 function csv_parse ($string, $delimiter = ",", $line_mode = true) {
    // This function parses on line-level first ($line_mode = true) and calls itself recursively to parse each line on field-level ($line_mode = false).
    // when in line mode, the delimiter is eol (\n, \r\n and \n\r). 
    // when in field mode, the delimiter is the passed $delimiter. 

    $delimiter = substr ($delimiter,0,1);                           // delimiter is one character       
    $length = strlen ($string);
    $parsed_array = array();
    $end_of_line_state = false;
    $enclosed_state = false;
    $i = 0;
    $field = "";
    do {
        switch (true) {
            case (!$enclosed_state && $end_of_line_state && ($string[$i] == "\r" && $string[$i-1] == "\n")) :
            case (!$enclosed_state && $end_of_line_state && ($string[$i] == "\n" && $string[$i-1] == "\r")) :
                // ...found second character of eol (\r\n of \n\r). Ignore
                $end_of_line_state = false;
                break;
            case (!$enclosed_state && !$end_of_line_state && ($string[$i] == "\n" || $string[$i] == "\r")) :
                    // ... found first character of eol \n, \r\n of \n\r
                $end_of_line_state = true;                  // eol can be two characters, so prepare for the second
                if ($field != "") {                     // ignore empty lines. Prohibited in csv
                    $parsed_array [] = csv_parse ($field, $delimiter, false); // recursive call to parse on field-level. Flush result
                };
                $field = "";                                // prepare for next one
                break;
            case (!$enclosed_state && $string[$i] == $delimiter && !$line_mode) : 
                // ...delimiter found
                $parsed_array [] = $field;              // flush field as new array element
                $field = "";                                // prepare for next one
                break;
            case ($string[$i] == "\"") :
                // ...encloser found
                if ($enclosed_state) {
                    if ($i < $length && $string[$i+1] == "\"") {
                        // ... escaped " found
                        if (!$line_mode) {
                            $field .= "\"";                     // when parsing fieldlevel, only " is part of the line
                        } else {
                            $field .= "\"\"";                   // when parsing line level, the escaping " is also part of the line
                        };
                        $i++;
                    } else {
                        // ...closing encloser found
                        $enclosed_state = false;
                        if ($line_mode) {
                            $field .= $string[$i];              // when parsing line level, the enclosing " are part of the line
                        };
                    };
                } else {
                    // ... opening encloser found 
                    $enclosed_state = true;
                    if ($line_mode) {
                        $field .= $string[$i];                  // when parsing line level, the enclosing " are part of the line
                    };
                };
                break;
            default:
                // ...regular character found
                $field .= $string[$i];
        };
        $i++;

        if ($i >= $length) {                                    // end of string
            if ($line_mode) {
                $parsed_array [] = csv_parse ($field, $delimiter, false); // recursive call to parse on field-level. Flush result.
            } else {
                $parsed_array [] = $field;                      // flush last field
            };
        };
    } while ($i < $length); 
    return $parsed_array;    
};
```